# How can I add VS Code snap as the default text editor in Krusader?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

How can I add VS Code as the default text editor in Krusader?

VS Code is installed as a Snap on my Ubuntu machine in `/snap/code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Krusader general config page and put `/snap/bin/code` in the "Editor" field. Related user docs: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/krusader/krusader/konfig-general.html.